# sending request parameters from one controller to service which contains init method in another controller based on routing url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I want logic  for  example : I have two controllers

1.builders controller 
2.filters controller

builders controller contains init method,HTTP service call.so i injected the service at the time of controller loading so i am getting the data from service and populating in HTML.

```
  <table  ng-init='homepalGroupProp.properties=hmpalprop(project.properties);'>
```

and my page routing to builders controller is

```
$routeProvider
                .when('/builders/:id', {
                    templateUrl: '../template/listpagefilter.html',
                    controller: 'buildersCtrl'
                })



var filters={
        $and: [
            {hp_builders_id:r.id}
        ]
        }

        sidemenu.controller('buildersCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$location', '$http', 'allServices','$document','PropertyDetails','$routeParams','$window', function (a, b, c, d, e,f,h,r,w) {


             e.projectListing(filters).then(function (result) {
                a.properties=result.data.items;
                 b.closeid=r.id;

                 },function (error) {

                 });

  b.$on('message', function (event, data) {
          var bedroom=data;
        var filters={
            $and: [
                {hp_builders_id:r.id,bedrooms:bedroom}
            ]
        }
        e.projectListing(filters).then(function (result) {
            a.properties=result.data.items;
            b.closeid=r.id;


            c.path("/builders/"+r.id).search({bedrooms:data});
        },function (error) {

        });


    });

        });
```

know filters controller [image]

so in filters controller i  am sending the request parameters from filter controller to builders controller but on that time project.properties value not changing in builders controller .how to change based on check boxes but init page is loading is good

filters controller :

```
     sidemenu.controller('filtersCtrl',['$scope','$rootScope','allServices','$window','$routeParams','$location',function (a,b,e,w,r,l) {


            a.unitnames = [{
                id:0,name: "1 BHK",selected:false
            },{
                id:1,name: "2 BHK",selected:false
            }, {
                id:2,name: "3 BHK",selected:false
            }, {
                id:3,name: "4 BHK",selected:false
            }];


a.OnItemClick=function (bedroom) {
        if(bedroom.selected == true){
             bedroomsIds.push(bedroom.id);
                var url=bedroomsIds.join(",");
            l.path("/builders/"+r.id).search({bedrooms:url});

        }
        else if(bedroom.selected == false){
            var index = bedroomsIds.indexOf(bedroom.id);
            if(index > -1){
                bedroomsIds.splice(index, 1);
                var url=bedroomsIds.join(",");
        l.path("/builders/"+r.id).search({bedrooms:url});
            }
        }
        if(bedroomsIds.length==0 && bedroom.selected ==false ){
            l.path("/builders/"+r.id).search({});
        }

    }
    });





});
```

SO I WANT TO change the project.properties values from filter controller request filters

main problem is [image]

Comment: Your question is a bit rambly, but look at the resolve property of the route.

Comment: @amyblankenship.are u understood the prblm iam facing

Comment: Vaguely. Have you looked in the angular docs for information on how to use the resolve property? You haven't done a great job of explaining your issue, but if you take a look at the docs you may be able to connect what understanding you do have of your problem to that information and see if it is the solution you need.